# Setting up HTML5 videos not working in FF or Safari

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

Making this fun web project at www.graysonearle.com/bluemen/index2.html and I'm running into all sorts of problems. Someone on SO helped me make sure the videos loaded before playing, but this solution only works on Chrome for me.
Here is the code:

```
    for (var i=0;i<16;i++) {
        document.write('<div class="vidBox" id="box'+i+'">');
        document.write('    <video class="vid" loop="loop" preload="metadata" id="vid'+i+'">');
        document.write('    <\/video>');
        document.write('<\/div>');
    }


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'videos/fullvid' + ext, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    console.log("got it");
    var myBlob = this.response;
    var vid = (window.webkitURL ? webkitURL : URL).createObjectURL(myBlob);
    // myBlob is now the blob that the object URL pointed to.
       for (var i=0;i<16;i++) {
        display(i,vid)
   }
  }
};
xhr.send();

       function display(i,vid){

    var video = document.getElementById("vid"+i);
    console.log(video);
    video.src = vid;

}
```

edit: to clarify, I want this 4x4 grid of videos to load (i'll add a loading screen later maybe) without auto playing necessarily. once loaded, clicking PLAY ALL should make them all play at once. clicking FISH makes a pattern in the movie grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your using  document.write to add these, but anyhow try adding the autoplay property to the video for example...

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your doctype. Please note that doctype for html5 is not same with earlier versions of html. Check your Doctype. It should be `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` Only.

EDIT
Proper tags for html5 videos. I think you might have to modify your syntax.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And take note of your video codecs also:

> MP4 = MPEG 4 files with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec
>
> WebM = WebM files with VP8 video codec and Vorbis audio codec
>
> Ogg = Ogg files with Theora video codec and Vorbis audio codec

Here is something else you might need for some browsers to play the video:

```
videoTag.src = "vid";
videoTag.load();
videoTag.play();
```

Comment: Uh oh, was set to <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"> I'll change it.... no change. Thanks, though!

Comment: Your syntax or the browser version should be the culprit. Have your tried test the code in plain html (without ajax and javascript). Just try playing video on your webpage using html5 to see how the browsers respond. I successfully play html5 videos on mine but they are all updated to recent versions. In as much as it works on chrome. It must have something to do with the browser rather than your code.

Comment: It's a pretty elaborate way of dealing with the fact that browsers don't play nice when I have 16 videos waiting to be played at the same time.

Comment: What does this return? console.log(video); Run a browser test here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Try this:
`videoTag.src = "vid";`
`videoTag.load();`
`videoTag.play();`
instead

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the "interesting" way that you are adding the videos to the HTML, you should rather rely on [HTML5 media events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents).

First of all, if you want the videos to actually load automatically, don't use `preload="metadata"`, as that'll only load the video metadata. Setting preload to `"auto"` should help. Alternatively, you could leave it out completely, since `auto` is the default value. (Though it seems that whenever Opera adds support for this attribute, they might make it default to `"metadata"`, so you might still be better off setting it explicitly to `"auto"`.)

AFter that, get rid of the whole XHR mess. Then, you could do something like this:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

for(var i = 0, ii = videos.length; i < ii; i++) {
  videos[i].addEventListener('canplaythrough',enablePlayback,false);
}

var videosLoaded = 0;

function enablePlayback(e) {
  videosLoaded++;
  if(videosLoaded === 16) {
    // enable a play button or do whatever you want
    // in this case: start playing all the videos at once
    for(var i = 0, ii = videos.length; i < ii; i++) {
      videos[i].play();
    }
  }
}
```

This code basically adds a listener for the `canplaythrough` event to all the videos, then as each video fires it, they'll increment the `videosLoaded` variable by one, and when the last video calls it and the `videosLoaded` hits 16 (the number of videos in your 4x4 grid), it'll call the `play()` on all the video objects.

You'll probably have to experiment with this quite a bit to get it right (I don't happen to have 16 small and short videos at hand myself to test this adequately), but this should take you to the right direction. You might want to look into `video.load()` as well if `preload="auto"` isn't downloading all the videos (could happen since there's so many of them).

If neither the `video.load()` nor `preload="auto"` seem to do the trick, you could set all videos to autoplay, then listen for the `play` event and pause them instantly (and then remove the `play` event listener). After that, have the same code for `canplaythrough` as before.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time. One problem I'm running into already is that the browser will just give up after loading 8~ videos. This was the initial reason for the XHR stuff, but maybe there is a better way out. Check http://graysonearle.com/bluemen/index3.html on Chrome

Comment: Oh wait. After reloading the page a few times it works. Maybe this connection sucks... let me know if it works for you. Thanks again.